# Is there a PHP web toolkit similar to Google Web Toolkit?

Tags: php, gwt, widget, toolkit

I've been playing with GWT lately, and I like the idea a lot. The only downside for me is Java, which I'm not a big fan of. (Please don't argue about Java being better than PHP, it's not the point here, really)

Do you know about any mature and efficient PHP toolkit providing a set of widgets just like GWT does ?

Thanks for your help :)

Edit : To rephrase it, I'm looking for a PHP framework that can generate most of the HTML code for the pages of my applications. [PHP-Ext](http://php-ext.quimera-solutions.com/) seems to be a pretty good example of what I'm looking for. Do you know about any other project of that kind ?

Nicolas

Comment: hopefully not.  compiling into javascript is about the worst idea ever

Comment: Compiling or code generation is not necessarily what I'm after. I'm more interested in programatically building UIs with PHP. A good example would be FCKEditor, which can be integrated into a webpage on the server side, by instanciating a class that encapsulates all what's needed to actually generate the JS code that'll display the editor on the client.

Comment: And why is this? Just out of interest.

Comment: Mostly because I like the idea of having a set of well-made widgets (like GWT does) that can be easily inserted in my pages on the server side. It looks to me like a good way to make good-looking UIs, to reuse code, and to help me make boring back-office apps faster, so I can spend my time focusing on more interesting stuff.

Comment: So you want a PHP framework that can generate Javascript/HTML/CSS?

Comment: Pretty much. I edited my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

maybe this FOSS project is something for your needs

http://php-ext.quimera-solutions.com/

Comment: This seems pretty interesting. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Delphi for PHP](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-for-php) will do what you want. I haven't used it though.

Answer (score 0):

[pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/) is pretty good.

As an aside, you could use any javascript library, like YUI or Dojo, server-side with [Aptana Jaxer](https://github.com/aptana/Jaxer).

Comment: This is a good example, but limited to charts generation :/ Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Delphi for PHP in this way. But the main idea is UI is also related to clients side so you always need javascript etc.. for achieving a web-UI. Check prado or yii framework which have component/event based architecture and js integrated.

Answer (score 0):

How about http://www.gwtphp.com/ ? It is GWT but it compiles to PHP instead of Java for the serverside. It is not yet officially published though, and I haven't tried yet.

Comment: **Warning**: The domain gwtphp.com now shows offensive (Not Safe For Work) content.

Comment: Besides that, I can only find references that indicate it is an RPC library (now?) and so is not a real equivalent of the original GWT.