# "PHP-ext" -like PHP widget libraries?

Tags: php, widget

I've asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306023/is-there-a-php-web-toolkit-similar-to-google-web-toolkit) a while back (actually nearly 1 year)...back then I was looking for a good widget library, generated from server-side in PHP. The most interesting candidate I find was [PHP-ext](http://php-ext.quimera-solutions.com/), but the project seems pretty much dead.

So one year later, is there any new open source project of that kind ? Or any widget (PHP-driven) that you use and find useful ?

Edit : Just to make it clear, what I'm looking for is a set of **standalone (that I can use without having to embrace a whole framework) PHP classes or libraries** to handle the generation of client-side (HTML+CSS+JS) widgets.

Comment: Have you had luck? I am desperately [looking for the same](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5436865/496176). I like [DHTMLX](http://www.dhtmlx.com) but I lack knowledge of JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

technically, PHP cannot do "widgets" in itself. You must use a Javascript framework (i.g. JQuery UI) to create the widgets and use PHP to handle the requests between the client and the server. I personally use Zend/ZendX with JQuery and it works fine. It's a big framework for small projects, but still use good coding practices.

In short, I would suggest you use JQuery UI and simply write your requests handlers manually. It's much simpler and concise this way.

Comment: I edited my question. Can Zend/ZendX be used efficiently as standalone modules ?

Comment: not that I've seen, no. Usually, frameworks do that to bind client with server scripting (so one only has to write server code and not worry much about javascript). You may have more chances on http://www.phpclasses.org/ ?